# Bought Wireless Adapter, Can't Use It

Tags: wifi, usb, vmware, kali-linux

I bought a cheap [Aztech WL572USB Wireless-N USB Adapter](http://www.aztech.com/support/index.php/networking-products/wireless-usb-adapter/wl572usb).

It clearly says it supports linux on the documentation but strangely doesn't even provide any way to set it up. I assumed it's plug-n-play but it didn't work, neither on my physical machine (I turned built-in wireless card off using <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>) nor on the intended Kali Linux Virtual Machine, the VMware says: "Connect Ralink Wireless Adapter" and when I do, I still can't see a wireless interface on `ifconfig` or `iwconfig`. how can I get this to work?

Here's an Aztech doc with two important information:
[LINK](ftp://ftp.aztech.com/Support/PHILIPPINES/junchavez/Wireless%20Adapters/WL572%20wireless%20N%20150/WL572%20wireless%20N%20150/AZTECH%20WL572USB%20%20Wireless-N%20USB%202.0%20Adaptor%20Product%20Specifications.doc)

It says it supports Linux, and it says it uses the Chipset: Ralink RT5370

Notes:

- Physical PC OS: Linux Mint Debian Edition.
- Virtual Machine OS: Kali Linux (target device).
- Virtualization: VMware.

Comment: Here are instructions from Debian for setting it up on the host machine: https://wiki.debian.org/rt2800usb

Comment: Have you loaded the firmware/driver?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: @derobert I followed the instructions in the link, still nothing on `ifconfig` or `iwconfig` or the Network Manager GUI.

Comment: Is the module loaded?

Comment: I don't know! I don't know how to do that.. I've input the lsusb and I do see this: `root@KaliHost:~# lsusb 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp.`

Comment: Try `ifconfig -a` (or `ip link`).

Answer (score 2):

Grepping the `drivers` directory of the kernel source tree for RT5370 turns up;

```
./net/wireless/rt2x00/Kconfig:         Supported chips: RT5370
```

`Kconfig` files are used to provide information for things like `make menuconfig` when configuring a kernel; this one happens to contain information for a number of Ralink PCI and USB based chipsets.  From the same entry:

> This adds support for rt53xx wireless chipset family to the **rt2800usb** driver.

Try `lsmod | grep rt2800`. If something turns up, the driver is loaded, skip to the next paragraph.  If not, try `sudo modprobe rt2800usb`.  If that fails, you need to follow [the guide derobert pointed ou](https://wiki.debian.org/rt2800usb)t.

To verify the interface is there, use `ip link` or `ifconfig -a`.

Comment: Tried `lsmod | grep rt2800` and it didn't show anything, did `sudo modprobe rt2800usb` then `lsmod | grep rt2800` and it showed: 

`lsmod | grep rt2800
rt2800usb              21813  0 
rt2x00usb              17426  1 rt2800usb
rt2800lib              72679  1 rt2800usb
rt2x00lib              41387  3 rt2x00usb,rt2800lib,rt2800usb
mac80211              427800  3 rt2x00lib,rt2x00usb,rt2800lib
crc_ccitt              12331  1 rt2800lib
usbcore               142158  7 uhci_hcd,rt2x00usb,rt2800usb,ehci_hcd,ehci_pci,usbhid`

Comment: ^ How do I do line breaks in replies? <br/> doesn't work.

Comment: I plugged the device on the Guest OS after that, and it still didn't work. And `ip link` or `ifconfig -a` don't either show wlan0, only eth0 and lo.

Comment: The driver is loaded, so presumably the interface also exists (the reason I said to use `ifconfig -a` is that just plain `ifconfig` only shows interfaces that are "up", and this one may be "down").  If you can confirm that, then you most likely have a working interface, you just have to configure it in order to connect to a WLAN (but that's a separate question).  WRT line breaks in comments, I've never seen any, I'd presume you can't.

Comment: I also installed wicd yesterday after following the guide on Debian wiki, still doesn't show any wireless extension. Thanks for your time, I guess I'll try returning the device and buy something that works as plug n play on linux.